# copy data rows with NULL column to another range in the same worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, windows-7, excel-2010

[image: pick NULL rows and then copy] I am working on EXCEL 2010 vba on Win 7.

I need to find data rows with NULL in one column. And copy them to another range in the same worksheet.

```
Option Explicit
    Sub find_null_entries()
      Dim ActSheet As Worksheet
      Dim myRange As Range
      Dim null_counter As Integer
      Dim res_rng As Range

      null_counter = 0
      Set ActSheet = ActiveSheet
      Set myRange = Selection

      Range("D1").Value = "NULL rows"

      For Each c In myRange
        If c.Value Is "NULL" Then
            null_count = null_count + 1
        res_rng  // copy the data entry to another range in the same worksheet, e.g. column D
        End If
     Next c
   End Sub
```

e.g.

```
  item     value
  person1  NULL   // find this row and then copy the **WHOLE** row to another range in the same worksheet
  person2  18
```

**UPDATE**

```
  copy "person1  NULL" to another two columns  
  example: from A2:B2  to  D2:E2
```

I have 5000 rows of data but maybe have 100  rows with "NULL". I need to find them and copy to toehr columns.

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: in what column your `"NULL"` values?

Comment: @simoco, in "value" column. Thanks !

Comment: I mean column name like column A, B, C?

Comment: @simoco, in the selected column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:**

```
Sub find_null_entries()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim null_counter As Long

    Set myRange = Intersect(Selection, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)

    Range("D1").Value = "NULL rows"

    For Each c In myRange
        If c.Value Like "*NULL*" Then
            null_counter = null_counter + 1
            Range("D1").Offset(null_counter).Resize(, 2).Value = c.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 2).Value
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: it does not work. nothing come out in column D. thanks !

Comment: I need to copy the whole row (not only the row number).

Comment: 1) copy in column D on the same row, or for first NULL record in first row, for second NULL record in second row and so on? 2) you select only single column B or both columns A:B?

Comment: for first NULL record in first row, for second NULL record in second row and so on

Comment: I select only single column B

Comment: "If UCase(Trim(c.Value)) = "NULL" Then" doe snot  work.

Comment: person in cell A2, NULL in cell B2. i want to copy them to cell D1 and E1 and so on.

Comment: How top post screen shot ?

Comment: see my post with pic.

Comment: I saw it. Try my updated answer (Select column B and run macro ). I tested my code with similar data and it works.

Comment: it works, Can you briefly explain "like" , why I cannot use " c.Value = "NULL" , thanks !

Comment: what is meaning of "Range("D1").Offset(null_counter).Resize(, 2)" ? the offset can be adjusted vertically ?  Thanks !

Comment: 1) `Like` Compares a string against a pattern: `string Like pattern`. Pattern can include wildcards (you can read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-RU/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) 2)I think `c.Value = "NULL"` didn't work because your cells contains additional spaces in the beggining or in the end (I'm not sure). 3) `Range("D1").Offset(null_counter)` means get cell `null_counter` rows below than `D1`. And `Range("D1").Offset(null_counter).Resize(, 2)` means get this cell and also additional cell to the right (resize range from one cell to two cells)

Comment: I really appreciate !